# Using spark-submit without --class argument

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm new to Spark and Scala, but hopefully this isn't a redundant/stupid question - I haven't been able to find the answer yet.

I have compiled a fat jar with the [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) tool, and the MANIFEST file includes the line `MainClass: com.package.MyMainClass`. However, spark-submit still demands that I use the `--class` argument to define the main class. From [this Spark configuration page](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html), I gather that spark-submit gets its configuration details from the `conf/spark-defaults.conf` file. My other properties (`spark.master`, `spark.app.name`) seem to load just fine without command line arguments, but I haven't been able to find a way to specify the project's main class in this file. I've randomly tried things like `spark.class` `main.class` and just `class`, but obviously stabbing in the dark isn't going that well.

Any ideas? I want to avoid having really ugly scripts to deploy applications to clusters when `spark-submit MyJar.jar` is so clean. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code of `org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.scala` [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/SparkSubmitArguments.scala), it looks like it should pick up your Main-Class manifest attribute:

```
mainClass = jar.getManifest.getMainAttributes.getValue("Main-Class")
```

I haven't tested this, but try replacing 'MainClass' with 'Main-Class'.